# What is the correct way to express a number with all its digits?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

I have the following table:

[image]

On the last column, I have expressed the numbers in billions as it is mentioned at the top. However, I want the last number (**Final sample size**) to be expressed fully. Is there a way that I can be specific about the fact that this is the full number and not rounded up in billions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but isn't that last sum 205 million rather than billion?

Comment: In addition to the comment from @SConroy, I find the number shown for the final total quite confusing: it is still in a column headed "(in billions)", which (according to your description) is **not** correct. If the final total is in different units from that shown at the top of the column, then the description at the left of that row should be amplified.

Comment: @TrevorD That is what I am looking for. As I have said, the column until the final cell I have expressed in billions, and I am looking for a way to suggest that the final number is the full or exact number (Exactly what you are suggesting)

Comment: But you still haven't addressed the issue raised by @SConroy that there is inconsistency as to whether your final total is in millions or billions!

Comment: @TrevorD ah sorry! The final number is expressed in all digits. It is 205 millions 813 thousands 022

Comment: How can the grand total be 205+ **million**, when the first item listed in the column is 26.5 **billion**, & the second item in the column is 6.01 **billion**?

Comment: That is the final sample size after all the filters. After filter number 7, there 205,813,022 observations left. It is not the sum of the steps

Comment: I still don't understand the table! If you start with 26.5 billion, and then subtract the figures given in the final column, you are still left with 9.71 billion! So I don't understand the table. In any case, if the number shown at the bottom is a *remainder* - not a *total* - then surely the last line should say "***Remaining** sample size*", not "***Final** sample size*"?  I'm voting to close this Q. because it's 'Not clear what you are asking'.

Comment: @TrevorD You start with the raw sample and then after you apply each filter, you are left with a number of observations. There is more information about this table in it's title in my document. Where it is explained how to look at each step. That was not my question. I was merely asking how to express a number not rounded up or down in any way. 
I agree with your suggestion about changing to the remaining sample size, but the other stuff... does not matter in my opinion, because it is not what I asked

Comment: On this site, it is not unusual for the underlying Q. not to be immediately apparent from the Q. as asked. Therefore, I (& others) sometimes take the view that we are not prepared to offer an answer without being sure that we fully understand what is being presented to us. In that respect - & as previously pointed out - your final figure shows a number in millions, but was in a column headed "billions" and is referred to in the last word of your Q. as "billions".  Therefore I was not prepared to offer an answer about how to refer to the final 'value' until I understood it's actual value.

Comment: I also refer you to the comments from @JasonBassford below the accepted answer - and which **postdate** your last reply to me -  that "the table is unclear and should be reformatted. (Personally, I'd remove the final cell from the table altogether and express it separately.)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93510/discussion-between-adrian-and-trevord).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common word for a number that is not rounded up or down, nor approximated in any way is "**exact**".

The fact that the number is without a decimal and expressed to nine significant figures should be enough for most people to realize it is the exact number, but you can indicate it specifically if you like.

Comment: Also note that, despite the comments under the question, the final cell is not necessarily part of the existing columns. It only appears to be because it is underneath all of the other rows that are underneath the headings. But by making it a single cell, it could easily be seen as not following those headings. After all, *final sample size* is not a *filtering step*, so the number shouldn't have to be *# of obs. (in billions)* either. It just means that the table is unclear and should be reformatted. (Personally, I'd remove the final cell from the table altogether and express it separately.)